# Slim Application Error class not found on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache, .htaccess, slim

I've just moved a site using the Slim Framework on Ubuntu 16.04, from a Plesk environment, to a server (Ubuntu 16.04) without a control panel. On the Plesk server everything was fine. My API (index.php) resides in

```
httpdocs/api/v2
```

Within that folder I had this htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Now I've moved away from Plesk, I have this (truncated) vhost file:

```
<Directory /var/www/somedomain.co.uk/httpdocs>
   Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
   DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</Directory>
```

However, this set up, if I go to somedomain.co.uk/api/v2/index.php I get the Slim page not found.

I've tried adding a Rewrite base to the htaccess eg

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /api/v2
# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php (have also tried ^ index.php)
```

But to no avail.

Not sure what else to try at this point - any help much appreciated.

**UPDATE** ... I can test a method in the API eg somedomain.co.uk/api/v2/pages/index but this is returning the Slim Application Error page (if that helps at all!)

**UPDATE** turns out the issue with a problem with the Composer install. With that fixed, I've got it working, using the above configuration in vhost file and this for the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Try to set the apache vhost `DocumentRoot` to `httpdocs/api/v2` and comment out ´RewriteBase /api/v2´. Change `RewriteRule . index.php` to `RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]`.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for getting back. Tried that but to no avail and in any event I need to retain the DocumentRoot as it is (ie without /api/v2). Have also tried changeing the <Directory> so it reads httpdocs/api/v2 ... but that doesnt work either .. it's very frustrating

Comment: Hi Daniel - I've updated the question - sorted it out in the end as problem was with Composer install. Thanks for helping out - much appreciated.